# TextView.setText() not working

Tags: android, textview, handler, settext

I have this piece of code...

```
class IncomingHandler extends Handler
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) 
    {

        String totalReceived = (String) message.obj;
        Log.i("TAG", "total received: " + totalReceived);
        totalTextView.setText("" + totalReceived);

        Log.i("TAG", (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) ? "UI thread" : "NOT UI thread");
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message received.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    };
};
```

I run my app and it works just fine, but if i recreate the activity, for instance by changing the device orientation, the text will not be updated. Note that i do receive the messages and they are successfully printed by LogCat.

Also note that on my last log i try to determine if I am running on the main thread. If that check is correct, I am indeed running on the UI thread...

Any ideas on what i might be doing wrong?

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: forgot to mention that when i recreate the activity, the text i get is the default one from the layout...

Comment: Post how you are hooking up / detaching from the handler.

Comment: Turns out that you were right. the way i pass the handler makes the diff. i was passing it when i was creating the service. now i pass it as a replyTo parameter each time i bind and it works

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `totalTextView` is still pointing to the TextView of the (now destroyed) previous activity.

If `class IncomingHandler` is a sub-class of Activity, it should be an easy job to make sure that during `onCreate()` you make sure to update it with `totalTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.__/* something */__);`

If the handler is not a sub-class of Activity, well, maybe it should be, or you should look into some more Android-Framework-High-Level stuff to update and call back the Activity (e.g. Loaders or UI-less fragments with `setRetainInstance(true);`)

ps.: some users will tell you to just override the destruction of the Activity by putting `configChanged` in the manifest. Although it might work at first moment, it's a poor quick fix, it's an unadvisable pattern that usually will lead to bigger problems in the future.

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a
>   last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information
>   about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Comment: as dymmeh commented on my post, it is important how you pass the handler to the service. my guess is that my service know about a handler that had no longer anything to do with the recreated activity.

Comment: Thanks so lot! I was using `this.text_field` as auto-generated by Kotlin so it was NOT obvious to me that this reference would become de-synced.

Answer (score 0):

as lint suggest handler should be static, make the handler staic and create a `weakReference` to the activity and then access the textview through the activity reference, I think It should work

Answer (score 0):

try to save instance 
add this

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
State s = new State(yourTextView.getText().toString());
outState.putSerializable(State.STATE, s);
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
State s = (State) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(State.STATE);
yourTextView.setText(s.getYourTextViewText());
 }
```